# \n Separated Search in Column

Tags: mysql

I have a district table, in which we store user’s preferred districts in district table district_id (varchar(250)) field(column). Value stored in this field is like  1 2 5 6 1 by using \n. So please tell me, how can i search in this specific column?

Comment: I think your storing value in wrong separator first. Second thing I want to confirm which server side language are you using >

Comment: Can you please show some code? You are just sending Theory, to get answer for that its simple "Just do a search". If you want a code, send us a code that you are having problems with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used mysql function FIND_IN_SET() and I got the desired result through this function.

I got help from this tutorial. 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Your design is absolutely horrible and this is why you are having this issue in the first place.

When you have a N-N relationship (a user can have many preferred districts and each district can be preferred by many users) you need to make a middle table with foreign keys to both tables.

You need:

1. A table for districts with only information about districts.
2. A table with users with only information about users.
3. A table for preferred districts by user with the district number and the user id as columns and foreign key constraints. This will make sure that any user can have an unlimited number of preferred districts with easy querying.

Comment: You might want to read something like this to help you. http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend performing searches on data stored that way, but if you are stuck it can be done with regular expressions.

You have to deal with starting and ending matches for a string as well. So a regular `LIKE` is not going to work.

[MySQL Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Give this SQL a try. To search for the number `5`

```sql
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `field` REGEXP '\\n?(5)\\n?';
```

If you want to match using the `LIKE` feature. It can be done using multiple rules.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `field` LIKE '%\\n5\\n%' OR LIKE '5\\n%' OR LIKE '%\\n5';
```

Note that you have to use a double `\` to escape for a new line.

Comment: i mean to say that districts_id is stored in the field (column) with the next line (\n). for instance, ID 1 then next line ID 2, then next line ID 5, all these id's are in a single field, and it's single value, so how i can search in it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just use a LIKE query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `preferred_districts` WHERE `district_id` LIKE '%6%';
```

To make sure it's the right one you'll receive (because this will also match id 16, 26, 674 etc.) you'll have to check manually if it's correct. In php (dunno if you use it) you could use the snippet below:

```
$id_field = '1 2 5 6 17';
$ids = explode("\n", $id_field);
if(in_array(6, $ids)) {
    echo 'Yup, found the right one';
}
```

**Important** Although the above will work, your database design isn't how it should be. You should create (what is sometimes called) a pivot table between the districts and the users, something like below.

```
(Table 'users_preferred_districts')

user_id | district_id
--------+------------
  2     |   1
  2     |  17
  9     |  21
```

Like this it's quite easy to retrieve the records you want...

Comment: Your answer is correct but a pivot table is not what you are describing here. Read your own Wikipedia link ! :D

Comment: lol :P didn't read the explanation, that's definitely something else indeed ;) we use that term however for tables in a many-to-many (n-n) relationship. Anyway, I hope the my explanation is clear enough like this ;)